# How to improve the structure of my database for a zip code and shipping lookup?

Tags: database-design, sqlite

We have page that shows shipping costs to any given zip code, and I'm trying to translate it into a form on the site that will do the dirty work and give the user the cost to their zip code. 
I strip off the last 2 digits of the zip since I don't need them in order to look up the zone.
The data that I have shows a **range** of zip codes. For example, the first entry is that any zip codes that start with 004 to 006 are in Zone 2.

Obviously, I don't want to create my table where in one row I list the data for "004", next line "005", etc. What is a good way to structure this so that I can take the zip that they input and compare it against a range of zip codes?

I'm using PHP and sqlite3, however I just can't wrap my head around the best way to structure this, once I do I can code it up no problem.

Comment: YOu are better off storing all zipcodes and thier zone in a table than the range. That way you can do a stroight join with no function inteh on clause which should perform much better. Anytime you resort to a function in a join, then you know your design is not optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a zip code contains numeric characters, it makes no sense as a number - you can't add it up - so you should store it as a string.

On that basis, your ZIP code ranges could be stored with fields for start and end range...
ie:

```
Zone |RangeStart | RangeEnd
   2 |       004 |      006
```

and your zip code data compared with a `between` clause

```
select * from address
     inner join zipcoderanges
     on substr(address.zipcode,1,3) between zipcoderanges.RangeStart and zipcoderanges.RangeEnd
```